# Next.js Router Dynamic URLs and the back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, next.js, router

I am using the `Router` from `next/router` in order to have a dynamic URL and load different content on the page:

```
Router.push('/contract', `/contract/${id}`);
```

The issue is the back button doesn't function as expected afterward.

1. After the function above runs the 1st click of the back button does **not** update the URL to the previous URL, but it **does** load the previous contract content.
2. The 2nd click of the browser back button **does** update the URL to the previous page URL, and the page content **remains the same** (which is now correct relative to the URL)

**Extra Note:** The main focus here is the browser back button but there is a breadcrumb back button that runs the window.history.back() function that works in this same unexpected manner (which makes sense).

Is the back button a known issue when using the push method of the Router, or dynamic URLs in general?  Is there a way to work around that with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function YourPage() {

  const router = useRouter();

  return (<div onClick={() => router.back()}>Back</div>);
}
```

> Navigate back in history. Equivalent to clicking the browser’s back button. It executes window.history.back().

Further reading

[next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Answer (score -1):

Try `.slice` !

```js
const goBack = () => {
   const { url } = useRouter();
   const prevUrl = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));

   return <a href={prevUrl}> Go Back </a>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that with the breadcrumb button, do you have any ideas for the browser back button?

Comment: ```Home / contract / contract 1``` these breadcrumb texts you want clickable right ?

Comment: No I'm wanting to be able to use the browser back button as expected.